# ¿Como hacer para que un metodo que devuelve MySqlConnection retorne Null?

Tags: mysql, c#, base-de-datos

Alguien me podria como hacer para que al momento de llamar este metodo y la base de datos no se establezca que me retorne un null

```
 private MySqlConnection Coneccion()
        {
            string myConnString = "...";
            try
            {
                MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection(myConnString);
                return myConnection;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error al conectar con la BD");
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Aqui trato de verificar si devuelve null pero aun asi que el link este mal entra por el if cuando no deberia ser asi :,c

```
public bool EjecutarComando_Bool(string mySelectQuery)
        {
            MySqlConnection myConnection = Coneccion();
            if (myConnection == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    myConnection.Open();
                    MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(mySelectQuery, myConnection);
                    myConnection.Close();

                    return true;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes tu conexión si retorna ```null``` por lo que entra al if esto pasa ya que puede que algo en tu cadena de conexión esté mal y por lo visto esta vacio, por lo que siempre te devolverá ```null```

Comment: Sip, esta vacia adrede porque quiero que me marque cuando alla error y retorne falso cuando halla error

Comment: Yyyy....? No veo algún error

Comment: Esta correcto tu codigo valida bien el `null` o que necesitas hacer explicate mejor